# Why Android Device Monitor doesn't show my threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-studio

When I launch my Android app that uses multiple threads (they do work and run), all I can see in Android Device Monitor is 11 threads, never less, never more, for my application.

They are named main, GC, Signal Catcher, JDWP, Compiler, ReferenceQueueDaemon, FinalizerDaemon, FinalizerWatchdogDaemon, Binder_1, Binder_2, Thread-6542.

There should be dozens of my own threads in that list. It seems as if my threads are just packed on single thread that runs them for a bit time each and repeats.

```
    for (Move m : moves) {
        MinMaxThread thread = new MinMaxThread(m, values, color);
        thread.run();
        threads.add(thread);
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        boolean working = true;
        while (working) {
            try {
                t.join();
                working = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Turns out I had used run() instead of start() for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start threads using `start()` method, not by calling `run()` directly.

Comment: @DamianKozlak This is what the OP did to solve their own problem, so it probably isn't "not an answer." Granted, it's a very short answer, but the problem was very simple.